# ArcGIS - Table columns lose formatting when I make a new copy of shapefile (Decimals, Thousands separator, Highlighting)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, attribute-table, formatting

When I make a copy of a shapefile or I join two shapefiles and then create a subsequent shapefile, my number type columns (in the attribute table) will default back to numbers with many decimals and no thousands separator. This after I've cleaned up every column the way I like it. I also lose the highlighting of any columns I have a highlight on.

I'm just looking for a way to avoid having to reformat every column if I happen to make a copy of the shapefile. That or is there a way to set a default of 2 decimal places and a thousands separator for the attribute table?

I'm trying my best to get away from shapefiles, but we need it to transfer between multiple programs.

Comment: Because shapefiles maintain their attributes in dBase .dbf files, and dBase files contain little or no information about thousands separators, precision, or column highlighting, you cannot hope to retain such information when transferring among programs. With careful programming and customization you could develop your own auxiliary file that carries along that information and is read by each program--but that would be a lot of work.